# German letters in From name not shown with Java Mail

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I'm sending mail with Java Mail. I use the following to set the sender info:

```
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@example.com", "Schaltfläche"));
```

Problem: When I send this message to my GMail, the sender is shown as **Schaltfl?che**.

In the source it's:

```
From: "=?ANSI_X3.4-1968?Q?Schaltfl=3Fche?=" <test@example.com>
```

Which looks...ok? At least it appears effort has been done to encode the **ä**.

So, what am I doing wrong? I could blame GMail, but that's a stretch, and testers are also seeing the error in other clients.

(Related but unrelated: The same name appears fine in the message body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through more searching, I found out two things:

- `ANSI_X3.4-1968` is apparently the canonical name for `ASCII`, which of course cannot encode **ä**. Also, `=3F` decodes as **?** (don't know why it needs encoding in the first place).
- There is a constructor `InternetAddress(mail, name, charset)`

So, I'm now creating the `InternetAddress` with `UTF-8`, which fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good to see that defining the charset for `InternetAddress` object fixed it for you.

Another solution (especially if you do not have possibility to change the code) would be to run JVM with defined encoding via corresponding VM argument:

`-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`